# Vue watch of sync non-required property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

We have synced property and watch to this prop at Child component. This property is set with default value (non-requeired)

Is there any way to force watching property change in child component in case if we don't provide prop from parent to child?

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-watch-sync-prop-bug-demo-lofei

I've added some code from two components below.

*- Parent.vue*

```vue
<template>
  <!-- watch inside not works if remove ':message.sync' here -->
  <Child :message.sync="message" />
</template>

<script>
import Child from "./Child";
export default {
  name: "Parent",
  components: { Child },
  data: function (params) {
    return {
      message: "",
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

*- Child.vue*

```vue
<template>
  <div>message: {{ messageValue }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Child",
  props: {
    message: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  computed: {
    messageValue: {
      get() {
        return this.message;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$emit("update:message", value);
      },
    },
  },
  watch: {
    message(value) {
      // this not executing
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out to add `immediate:true` to the watch property :

```
 watch: {
    message:{
      handler(value) {
     
      },
      immediate:true
    }
  },
```

Comment: This isn't working. Try by yourself https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-watch-sync-prop-bug-demo-lofei

Comment: You're missing the prop binding it should be `<Child :message="message"/>`

Comment: This property is not required (cause I set default value). So that's my question: why watch not works if I skip this binding and how can I force watch for this property?

Comment: but it renders the default message in the first rendering https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-watch-sync-prop-bug-demo-forked-gpig6?file=/src/components/Child.vue

Comment: Ohhhhh my bad. I just understood that I'm emitting update but the actual value doesn't change cause prop was not bound and it does not save new value...

Comment: I think that you're tired and you couldn't  concentrate :)